# combine dataframe in the bottom of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

What I would like to combine both of this below dataframe.

```
    > am_R3_1
                 Group.2  x.x      x.y
     2   clearterminate     3   21
     3  display.cryptic    86   30.127
     4            price    71   898
    41               AM   160   316.37

    > am_R3_2
      Group.2  x.x  x.y
    1    ping    1    5
    2      1Y    1    5
```

I would like to get the final result smiliar to below for all Group.1 . Please advise which function I can use to get the following result ?

```
        Group.2          x.x   x.y
     2  clearterminate     3    21
     3  display.cryptic   86    30.127
     4  price             71   898
    41  AM               160   316.375
    1   ping               1     5
    2   1Y                 1     5
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove the extraneous stuff at the top.  (Notice also that you used the variable name `am_R3` twice, so I renamed these as `am_R3_1` and `am_R3_2`)

Comment: There's also `rbind.fill` in `plyr` package that I find useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want `rbind`:

```
result<-rbind(am_R3_1, am_R3_2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `rbind` to combine two data.frames by row.  This will append the rows of two data.frames if all of the columns are matching:

```
rbind(am_R3_1, am_R3_2)
```

For future reference, there is also a function `cbind` that appends columns to an existing data.frame.

See `?rbind` or `?cbind` for more help.