# How to subtract 2 columns with dtype = object within data frame to form a new column of the difference pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a merge data frame(mdf) which the 2 data frames are retrieved from SQL. I wish to create a new col within mdf which will be the subtraction of existing 2 columns.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229608/combine-dataframe-in-the-bottom-of-another-dataframe

Comment: That's an R data.frame; I think he's after a pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "merge data frame," but here's a sketch of what you might be after. Please elaborate a little your question so it will be more useful to others.

```
df = pd.read_sql('select ....', some_sql_connection)

df['difference'] = df['some column name'] - df['another column name']
```

Also, referring to the title of your question where you mention `dtype=object`, data extracted from a SQL database sometimes defaults to the generic `object` datatype, even if it is actually numeric. (This is not ideal, and better handling of datatypes to and from SQL databases is being actively improved for a future release of pandas.)

For now, before manipulating your data, you might want to run `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` if you have all numerical data. See [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html).

Comment: thanks Allan, I did that but i had this error 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Comment: this is error msg:
TypeError:Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-6a2188062e75> in <module>()
----> 1 mdf['Difference'] = mdf['Value_x'] - mdf['Value_y']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Comment: Great, glad it worked. I suspect ``convert_objects`` was the key here -- maybe you discovered that yourself. Cheers.